# How to make tesseract recognize number 0 with open top right corner which is included in EU plates?

Tags: image, ocr, tesseract, digits

I have this character image:

[image]

This Image of 0 is similar to ones found in some eu plate cars. for example this image:

[image]

How to make tesseract (if possible) to recognise the 0 in the image as 0 in python or any other language? Currently on its on it is recognize it as u. Of-course if I croped the 0 and the 2 together is recognises them as digits (0 2) as there is nothing else but I want to recognize every single character where any general plate can have any number of characters in any order. Do I need to retrain tesseract? Thank you.

Comment: Openalpr has trained tesseract for this font. Have you tried using their data? It open sourced with a GPL license. https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/tree/master/runtime_data/ocr/tessdata

Comment: I will try and see

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I keep the question or close it?

Comment: Your choice. You can write an answer yourself and accept it. The solution could be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the trained font (tesseract) from this git repository:

https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/tree/master/runtime_data/ocr/tessdata

They have trained data for various car plates and use can use any of them for your plate OCR.